# allure-results does not exist Jenkins python pycharm

Tags: python, jenkins, pycharm, allure

i am unable to resolve the allure-report generation in Jenkins. I am able to see reports locally on the machine but not on Jenkins.

[image: Project Structure]

When running locally generates the correct allure-report

C:\Users\User\Downloads\Selenium-Python-Example-main\tests>pytest test_login.py  -v -s --capture sys -rP --alluredir=target\allure-results  --browser  firefox

Below is the Jenkins

[image: Jenkins_command]

[image: Jenkins Config]

[image: Allure_Blank report]

Can someone Please help me, tried all the options still unable to resolve the error report.

Comment: Can someone please help me struck from last  2 days